# Hosting domain on Google cloud Joomla VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I got domain from a registrar (enom), I made NS records in Google cloud DNS and mapped 'A' record to the Joomla IP address then added this info in enom but the domain doesn't point anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

if you 'made' the NS records that could be your problem since it is;-

1. Zone name - just an identifier
2. DNS name -  the domain name
3. Description - optional..

then the system automatically assigns the NS
you enter these 4 NS at the Registrar's panel

4. then the A record and ip - this is obtained from  Compute->Compute Engine-->VM instances
5. then a CName for www if required

That's really it and it should work
Using https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
you can query the system, this command;-

gcloud dns managed-zone get "whatyoucalledthezone"

will return the existing NS

have a look at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/lamp/setting-up-dns

Dig can be useful for troubleshooting / to be sure the records are what you think they are;- since I do not have points for more links you could search for

using-dig-for-dns-verification-and-troubleshooting